# Angular populate data to drop down

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have a return data in `json` format, how can I use `ng-model` to load the data back to dropdown as a default value?

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-2">
            <h5 class="over-title">Category</h5>
            <ui-select ng-model="product.categories.selected" theme="bootstrap">
                <ui-select-match placeholder="Select Category" ng-model="product.name">
                    {{$select.selected.name}}
                </ui-select-match>
                <ui-select-choices repeat="item in categories | filter: $select.search">
                    <div ng-bind-html="item.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
                </ui-select-choices>
            </ui-select>
        </div>
```

The json as follow:

```
Object { category: "Sightseeing & Tours" }
```

the current `ng-model=product.name` is used to populate options when someone create new product. Now when they edit back the form, the dropdown should list the data that previously saved which is returned by above `json`.

The function for dropdown list options when create new product:

```
$scope.categories = function(){
       Account.getCategoryList()
        .then(function(response){

            $scope.categories = response.data;
        })


        .catch(function(response){
            console.log(response.data.messages);
        });

    };
```

The one that return `json` when someone edit back the form

```
$scope.produk = {};
    $scope.getProductToEdit = function(id){
      Account.getProductToEdit(id)
        .then(function(response){

            $scope.produk = response.data.product;
            console.log($scope.produk); ---> Object { category: "Sightseeing & Tours" }
            return $scope.produk;
        })
        .catch(function(response){

        })
    }
```

New form mode:

[image]

Edit form mode:

[image]

How can I replace the default dropdown with what returned from `json` in edit mode. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the dropdown, select-2 directive can be used which addresses this issue.Refer the following link :
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2